# VB, T-SQL: How to convert a Select Case to proper T-SQL (2012) syntax

Tags: sql, vba, t-sql, vb6

I am continuing migrating visual basic code to a SQL stored procedure. This is something I am doing for the first time, and I am not sure as what is the best practice, or approach when converting the code.

I am dealing now with a Select Case statement. It is dependent on the value of the leftmost or rightmost characters of an input string, based on those values, the source SELECT part of the INSERT statement is determined.

I was wondering if I could get some coding help, something that would help me start with, or a recommendation on how this can be efficiently managed by T-SQL code. Any help is appreciated it.

Here is the template of the VB Select Case statement:

```
    Select Case Left(ID, 2)

    Case "MN"                                        

        QSQL = "INSERT INTO table "

        Select Case Right(PID, 2)                        

            Case "LC", "LS", "LM"

                QSQL = QSQL & "SELECT columns " 
                            & "FROM table " _
                            & "WHERE ((column) = '" & ID & "'));"

            Case Else

                If Mid(ID, 3, 1) <> "0" Then

                    QSQL = "INSERT INTO table "
                    QSQL = QSQL & "SELECT columns"
                    QSQL = QSQL & "FROM table WHERE column ='" & PID & "';"

                Else

                    If InStr(PID, "_") = 10 Then                                    

                        QSQL = QSQL & "SELECT columns "
                        QSQL = QSQL & "FROM table"
                        QSQL = QSQL & "WHERE column = '" & ID & "';"
                    Else

                        QSQL = QSQL & "SELECT columns "
                        QSQL = QSQL & "FROM table "
                        QSQL = QSQL & "WHERE column = '" & ID & "';"
                    End If

                End If

        End Select

    Case "CL"

    Case "GT"

    Case "SC"

    Case "MS"

    Case Else

End Select
```

Comment: if you know the CASE syntax in SQL, it should be strait forward. is there anything special in this? Have you tried any query so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` in VB is for control of logical flow, `CASE` in T-SQL is an *expression* intended to return a single value; the two are not equivalent despite their shared name.

You can port what you have to SQL using `IF/ELSE` in place of the `SELECT CASE`.  You cannot replicate it exactly without using dynamic SQL/`sp_ExecuteSQL` as you build statements in strings, instead use complete inline statements in your SP:

```
IF (RIGHT(@PID, 2) IN ('LC', 'LS', 'LM'))
   INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT COLUMNS ... WHERE COLUMN = @ID
ELSE IF ...
```

An alternative would be to keep the logic in B and call different procedures as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it is very helpful. I have a question, if you take a look, the VB CASE begins with Select Case Left(ID, 2) Case "MN", then within that Case, there is another one: Select Case Right(PID, 2)  Case "LC", "LS", "LM". How will these be done using IF/ ELSE? would a nested be the choice? Thank you.